# Sending server-side variables to client-side JS in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, client-side

app.js (Server-side JS)

```
var Object = {
    name: "Name",
    id: 200,
    branch: "CS"
}
```

public/js/index.js (Client-side JS)

I have been digging on this for long but couldn't find a solution. I just want my "Object" variable to export to my client-side JS file(index.js) but I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = Object;
```

or:

```js
export default Object;
```

may help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import